# Display a double with no Decimals?

Tags: swift, double, decimal

I would like to display a `Double` with no decimals in Swift.

The `location.speed` comes from Map Kit.
This is what I have tried:

```
let kmt = location.speed * (18/5)
let theKmt = Double(round(10*kmt)/10)

statusLabel.text = "km/t\(theKmt)"
```

Comment: What do you mean by no decimals?  Should you round up?  down?

Comment: Cast the rounded value to an `Int` instead of a `Double`.

Answer (score 7):

You're probably looking for this:

```
let d: Double = 1.12345
statusLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", d)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 let d: Double = 1.23456
 let doub: Double = 1.23456
 print(String(format: "%.0f", d))
 print(Int(doub))
```

Comment: Casting a double value into Int will crash if the double value is greater than the range of Int.

Fatal error: Double value cannot be converted to Int because the result would be greater than Int.max: file

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all the response! 
I really appreciate it.

I solved my problem this way:

```
 let kmt = location.speed * (18/5)
    let kmtLabel = Int(kmt)



    statusLabel.text = "\(kmtLabel)"
```